# Output directory path both locally and on remote server for ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, output-directory

I've builded a ASP.NET RESTful service project with C#. I need to add some custom XML files with configuration, which I need to read and process at runtime.

I added the XML files to my project and set the property "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy Always".

To open the file I used the following snippet:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "configuration.xml");
```

This works fine when I publish the project to the server but if I run the web services locally the output directory changes and I have to append `bin` to the beginning of the path like:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin\\configuration.xml");
```

Is there any way to get the correct output directory for both local and remote server?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do instead of copying your files to the output folder is to keep them in the root project folder (or some sub-folder structure) and use the [HttpServerUtility.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method to resolve the correct physical path to the file on the server (both local and remote).

So in your scenario, `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("configuration.xml")` would return a path like `C:\MyWebApp\configuration.xml` which you can then load as normal.

Comment: Do I have to set any build action for the files to stay on the root project folder?

Comment: No build action required, these would simply act as content files for your website/service that should be deployed to the server.

Comment: The assembly managing the XML files was a different one than the one running the web services. I ended up using the `HttpServerUtility.MapPath()`and moving the resource files into the web services assembly.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the property Build Action as "Embedded Resource" of configuration.xml and then can access the file by using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream()

e.g. Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(MyPRoject.configuration.xml)